# Sharing many folders between two Linuxes

Tags: filesystems, partition, shared-folders, shared-partition

I have dual boot Arch and Ubuntu, and what I want to do is to share folders such as *Documents*, *Downloads*, *Desktop* e.g. so I can use them in both operating system

The usual way is just to create new partition and mount it to both systems (also editing */etc/fstab* to auto-mount on boot), but, as I said earlier, I want to share many folders. So is there a simplier way than creating many file systems?

Comment: if your dual-boot linux is all on one disk having multiple partitions, you would just mount that partition you want to access whether it is Arch mounting Ubuntu or Ubuntu mounting the Arch partition.  Not sure what you're asking exactly and how to interpret *I have dual boot Arch & Ubuntu*.  Even if they are on separate disks you would just mount the correct partition that has the folders you want to access.  if all the disk(s) are physically connected within one computer then there's no *sharing* to do which implies there is network separation which it doesn't sound like there is.

Comment: I have both distros on the same disk (*/dev/sda*), but I don't want to mount whole Arch in Ubuntu for example, I only want to have some folder like *Documents, Downloads* and other

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use same username and home directory for both distro (single user scenerio), but that will likely break some config.

Secondly, you can symlink the required folders from one to another. Say the arch user name is archy and  Ubuntu user name is bunty.

- create a group with same GID in both distro.
  `sudo groupmod -g 3000 shared`.
- Add your user to this group in both distro.
  `usermod -a -G shared archy`,
  same goes for bunty
- Then change the group of the directories with `chown` or `chgrp` command,  like `chown -R  :shared Documents`.
- Symlink the directory. Say, we keep the original directory in archy's home and symlink in bunty's home
  `ln -s /home/archy/Documents /home/bunty/Documents`

Now you can access your files from both distro. If you have only one user in each distro, you don't have to create a group because the UID are likely the same (1000) for both user  and they have full permission on each others files'

Comment: How can I use `ln -s` if */home/archy* is on */dev/sda3* and */home/bunty* on */dev/sda2*?

Comment: I do not know how to achive such fit. They are different partitions. It is like you have two shelves seperated by a wooden partition and own doors. There is no way you can access one from another by opening one door. It is either all or nothing